# Help needed regarding updation of currency table updation

Tags: apex

I am trying to update the currency table in salesforce using the below code:

```
Http h = new Http();
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/CurrencyType/04wb0000000KzHlAAK?_HttpMethod=PATCH');
req.setBody('{ "ConversionRate" : 2.5 }');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setMethod('POST');
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

This works fine when we provide the static values but how to pass the dynamic values to ConversionRate in `req.setBody` method.

Comment: req.setBody('{ "ConversionRate" : '+YourVariavble+' }');

doesn't this work in your code to provide dynamic value?

Comment: @VarunChaddha No its not accepting like this. we will get a bad request with status code 400

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to do this but here is one  way to do this ,

```
 Map<String,double> mapstrBydouble=new Map<String,double>();
 double d=5.5;
 mapstrBydouble.put('ConversionRate',d);
 body=JSON.serialize(mapstrBydouble);
 system.debug('body'+JSON.serialize(mapstrBydouble));

req.setBody(body);
```

Comment: thanks for your code.
but i will be facing the problem in setEndPoint method where i also need to pass the id of currency dynamically. Is it possible to do the same.